# Warning: `importlib-metadata` version is incompatible with `setuptools`

Tags: python, pandas, setuptools, python-importlib

I imported pandas library on jupyter notebook
After that a warning appears like `importlib-metadata` version is incompatible with `setuptools`.
And suggest for This problem is likely to be solved by installing an updated version of `importlib-metadata`.

I have done suggested by installing update version from `importlib-metadata`

Then I restart the kernel and run the program, But still the same warning appears as before.

This is the program i made

```
import pandas as pd
```

And a warning appears like:

> C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py:23:
> UserWarning: `importlib-metadata` version is incompatible with
> `setuptools`. This problem is likely to be solved by installing an
> updated version of `importlib-metadata`.   warnings.warn(msg)  #
> Ensure a descriptive message is shown.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in a Centos 7 machine. It was solved by:
pip install importlib-metadata==4.12

Comment: Which version of python and setuptools did you have?